# 'No adapter for endpoint' exception - apache-camel with spring-boot & spring-ws

Tags: spring, web-services, apache-camel, spring-boot, spring-ws

**JVM** 1.8.0_45
**apache-camel** 2.15.2
**spring-ws** 2.2.1
**spring-boot** 1.2.4

I am trying to use apache-camel (2.15.2) within a spring-boot application to handle incoming web service calls.

I created an initial working spring boot project (no camel) following the guidelines here http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

I then attempted to integrate the Camel: Spring Web Services component as a Consumer to handle incoming web service requests following guidelines in the 'Exposing Web Services' section here http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html

**WebServiceConfig.java**

```
import org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.bean.CamelEndpointMapping;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    // default wsdl stuff here...

    // exposing the endpoint mapping bean here rather than in spring-ws-servlet.xml (seems to work)
    @Bean  public CamelEndpointMapping  endpointMapping() {
        return new CamelEndpointMapping();
    }
}
```

ClaimRouter.java

```
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JaxbDataFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ClaimRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat(false);
        jaxb.setContextPath("uk.co.example.claim.ws.v2"); 

        // comment @PayloadRoot annotation in ClaimEndpointV2.java to enable requests to be mapped to this camel route
        from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2}getClaimRequest?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping")
        .to("log:uk.co.example.claim.ws.v2?level=INFO")
        .unmarshal(jaxb)
        .process(new ClaimProcessor())
        .marshal(jaxb);
    }
}
```

According to the log (below) incoming requests are successfully mapped to my Camel Consumer, but then it fails with 'No adapter for endpoint'

```
[2015-06-24 13:22:03.981] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-6] --- WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter: Transforming [/ws] to [http://localhost:8090/ws]
[2015-06-24 13:22:03.983] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-6] --- MessageDispatcherServlet: Successfully completed request
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.544] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter: Accepting incoming [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection@70863933] at [http://localhost:8090/ws]
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.547] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- received: Received request [SaajSoapMessage {http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2}getClaimRequest]
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.547] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping: Looking up endpoint for [{http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2}getClaimRequest]
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.547] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- SoapMessageDispatcher: Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@5fdbde50] has no mapping for request
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.547] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping: Looking up endpoint for []
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.547] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- SoapMessageDispatcher: Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@50bf4dcb] has no mapping for request
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.547] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- SoapMessageDispatcher: Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping@8b5028a] has no mapping for request
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.548] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- SoapMessageDispatcher: Endpoint mapping [org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.bean.CamelEndpointMapping@7a9ff5b1] maps request to endpoint [Consumer[spring-ws://rootqname:(http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2)getClaimRequest?endpointMapping=%23endpointMapping]]
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.548] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- SoapMessageDispatcher: Testing endpoint adapter [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter@5a1e093a]
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.549] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver: Resolving exception from endpoint [Consumer[spring-ws://rootqname:(http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2)getClaimRequest?endpointMapping=%23endpointMapping]]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [Consumer[spring-ws://rootqname:(http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2)getClaimRequest?endpointMapping=%23endpointMapping]]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.549] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- SimpleSoapExceptionResolver: Resolving exception from endpoint [Consumer[spring-ws://rootqname:(http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2)getClaimRequest?endpointMapping=%23endpointMapping]]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [Consumer[spring-ws://rootqname:(http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2)getClaimRequest?endpointMapping=%23endpointMapping]]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.549] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- SoapMessageDispatcher: Endpoint invocation resulted in exception - responding with Fault
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [Consumer[spring-ws://rootqname:(http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2)getClaimRequest?endpointMapping=%23endpointMapping]]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpointAdapter(MessageDispatcher.java:302)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:235)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.reessageDispatcher.java:176)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catali.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.554] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- sent: Sent response [SaajSoapMessage {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Fault] for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://example.co.uk/claim/ws/v2}getClaimRequest]
[2015-06-24 13:22:13.556] boot - 6892 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-7] --- MessageDispatcherServlet: Successfully completed request
```

My gradle dependencies are as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws") {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter") {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-web")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    compile("org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.2")
    compile("org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot:2.15.2")
    compile("org.apache.camel:camel-spring-ws:2.15.2")
    compile("org.apache.camel:camel-jaxb:2.15.2")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'
    compile("wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.1")
    jaxb("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.4-1")
    compile sourceSets.generated.output
}
```

I've researched a large number of *No adapter for endpoint* problems and most of them seem to be caused by the return type of the endpoint. However, I'm just creating a camel route, so presumably the **camel-spring-ws** integration should be providing the actual endpoint.

Am I missing a key piece of configuration/annotation or is there a more fundamental problem (some version incompatibility, perhaps)?  Any help or insights much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

When spring boot is used, it registers just `DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter` that configures annotation driven Spring WS programming model. This makes it possible to use the various annotations like `@Endpoint`, `@Payload` auto detected.

As in our case, spring-ws endpoint has to hand over ws requests to camel endpoint, `DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter` won't do that job for us.

Below is the part of the code in the spring framework that does the end point adapters registration,

```
private void initEndpointAdapters(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

    if (endpointAdapters == null) {
        Map<String, EndpointAdapter> matchingBeans = BeanFactoryUtils
                .beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(applicationContext, EndpointAdapter.class, true, false);


        if (!matchingBeans.isEmpty()) {
            endpointAdapters = new ArrayList<EndpointAdapter>(matchingBeans.values());
            Collections.sort(endpointAdapters, new OrderComparator());          
        }

        else {
            endpointAdapters =
                    defaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategies(EndpointAdapter.class, applicationContext);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("No EndpointAdapters found, using defaults");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When we use spring-boot, `DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter` gets registered and hence the first 'if block' runs and hence it doesn't register other adapters like `MessageEndpointAdapter`, `PayloadEndpointAdapter` etc.

What we need in this case is, other than `DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter`, have to register `MessageEndpointAdapter` as well to offload spring-ws to camel endpoints.

So in `WebServiceConfig` class, add the below code,

```
@Bean
    public EndpointAdapter messageEndpointAdapter() {
        return new MessageEndpointAdapter();
    }
```

then the handover magic happens.

> [MessageEndpointAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/MessageEndpointAdapter.html) is required for spring-ws and camel
>   handover.

Comment: This is the case with spring boot annotations, bit if you use xml configuration, this won't happen as the else block gets activated in the latter case.

Comment: Great explanation. Worked like a charm for me. Had the same exact issue.

Comment: If you used a Java Based Configuration this Bean is a life saver.